# Blazor Reload Issue

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

When I make changes to component, the page doesn't udate automatically, I have to restart blazor server for changes to take effect, is there a way to fix this issue?

Haven't tried anything so far as I don't really know how to fix this issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dotnet run, I had to use dotnet watch